# Export all msbuild imported targets to a file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, build, msbuild

I want to export all targets imported in an msbuild file.

I have an msbuild file named Msbuildtest.proj contains .targets files imported.Files are imported using import statement.All these files are in different location and i have to go to each folder location every time to open the files.Is there any way to export all imported target to a single file,so that i can save  lot of time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you open a command prompt and navigate to the location of MsBuildtest.proj.

Then you "preprocess" the MsBuild script with an MsBuild command switch like so.

```
msbuild.exe MsBuildTest.proj /pp >MsBuildTest.txt
```

This will flatten the MsBuild import taxonomy into standard output and pipe the output to a text file via the > operator.